# Flutter test GraphQL query

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-graphql

I want to test my GraphQL Query. I have my GraphQL client, and I use a remote datasource to do my requests.

```
class MockGraphQLClient extends Mock implements GraphQLClient {}

void main() {
  RemoteDataSource RemoteDataSource;
  MockGraphQLClient mockClient;

  setUp(() {
    mockClient = MockGraphQLClient();
    RemoteDataSource = RemoteDataSource(client: mockClient);
  });
  group('RemoteDataSource', () {
    group('getDetails', () {
      test(
          'should preform a query with get details with id variable',
          () async {
        final id = "id";
        when(
          mockClient.query(
            QueryOptions(
              documentNode: gql(Queries.getDetailsQuery),
              variables: {
                'id': id,
              },
            ),
          ),
        ).thenAnswer((_) async => QueryResult(
            data: json.decode(fixture('details.json'))['data'])));

        await RemoteDataSource.getDetailsQuery(id);

        verify(mockClient.query(
          QueryOptions(
            documentNode: gql(Queries.getDetailsQuery),
            variables: {
              'id': id,
            },
          ),
        ));
      });
    });
  });
}
```

**I would like to know how to mock the response of my query. Currently it does not return a result, it returns null**
But I don't understand why my query returns null, although I have mocked my client, and in my "when" method I use a "thenAnwser" to return the desired value

```
final GraphQLClient client;

  ChatroomRemoteDataSource({this.client});

  @override
  Future<Model> getDetails(String id) async {
    try {
      final result = await client.query(QueryOptions(
        documentNode: gql(Queries.getDetailsQuery),
        variables: {
          'id': id,
        },
      )); // return => null ????

      if (result.data == null) {
        return [];
      }
      return result.data['details']
    } on Exception catch (exception) {
      throw ServerException();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just to get some confusion out of the way, are both code snippets still in sync? I see 'RemoteDataSource' vs 'ChatroomRemoteDataSource' and 'getDetailsQuery' vs 'getDetails'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument on which `when` should mock an answer for is quite complex. You might be easier to just use `any` in your test case.

```
when(mockClient.query(any)).thenAnswer((_) async => QueryResult(
        data: json.decode(fixture('details.json'))['data'])));
```

`any` is provided by Mockito to match any argument.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, however, I am not able to use any in null safe. Do you know what can we use in that case?

Comment: Null safety added a level of complexity to Mockito. There are multiple approaches documented for null safety: https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md
Personally, I use the generated mocks approach.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the

> graphql_flutter: ^5.0.0

you need the add source as null or QueryResultSource.network, when call method **when** can you pass **any** so you don't need to pass `QueryOptions( documentNode: gql(Queries.getDetailsQuery), variables: { 'id': id, }, )`,

here is final code:
`when(mockClient.query(any)).thenAnswer((_) async => QueryResult( data: json.decode(fixture('details.json'))['data'], ,source: null)));`

Answer (score 0):

`any` is not accepted with `graphQLClient.query(any))` as it accepts non nullable `QueryOptions<dynamic>`

Using `mockito: ^5.1.0` , you will get the warning:  `The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'QueryOptions<dynamic>'`

I solved it by creating the mocked QueryOptions as:

```
class SutQueryOption extends Mock implements QueryOptions {}

void main() {
SutQueryOption _mockedQueryOption;
....

setUp(() {

SutQueryOption _mockedQueryOption = MockedQueryOptions();
....

});

when(mockClient.query(_mockedQueryOption)).thenAnswer((_) async => ....
```